# Added plugins/features in Text Component don't appear in toolbar for common user in inplace editing mode

Tags: aem

I developed a RTE component following [Configure the Rich Text Editor](https://forums.adobe.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelpx.adobe.com%2Fexperience-manager%2F6-4%2Fsites%2Fadministering%2Fusing%2Frich-text-editor.html%23Understandtheconfigurationpathsandlocations) , it inherits core/wcm/components/text/v2/text. I added cq:editConfig for it. When editing content in inplace editing mode on a author page, admin can see added plugins/features  in toolbar normally. But for common user, added features don't appear in toolbar.

I have tried following ways but they don't help:
1. Move my config to another folder, and added configPath property under node RTE/cq:editConfig/cq:inplaceEditing to point to it. 
2. Tried to rename config to some other name e.g myconfig, but got errors "Cannot read property 'disableXSSFiltering' of undefined".

I'm using AEM 6.4. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by common user? are they authors with write permission?

Comment: Yes, authors who will be responsible for edit page contents. They do have write permission.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known behavior to author user when editing in inplace editing mode.
Please ignore this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please delete this question if it is not valid. Or provide some documentation on your answer.

Comment: Could you tell me how to delete it? I didn't find the document for this moment.